# train_test_split returning different forms of variable

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I came across the following link:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html
In this there is the following piece of code :

```
import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
>>> X, y = np.arange(10).reshape((5, 2)), range(5)
```

Why is `X` in capital and `y` in lowercase? Is there any particular reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

The X and Y sometimes are matrices. In math notation, it is common to write vector variable names in lower case and matrix variable names in upper case.

Comment: So `X` could be a matrix and `y` is always a column vector?

Comment: @ravan not always. See https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/multiclass.html#multilabel-classification-format